# HAproxy Configuration - Wordpress + phpMyAdmin + mariadb in Docker

Tags: docker, configuration, haproxy

N00b here, I'm trying to create a configuration file for HAproxy, but I'm having some understanding problems about this topic.

So, for this example I want to be able to load wordpress when I'm accessing http://VMip and when I use http://VMip/phpmyadmin to be able to create database / users etc using phpMyAdmin.

Below is my HAproxy config file.

If you need more info I will happily provide them.
Thank you in advance.

```
global
    log          fd@2 local2
    chroot       /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile      /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn      4000
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats expose-fd listeners
    master-worker

resolvers docker
    nameserver dns1 127.0.0.11:53
    resolve_retries 3
    timeout resolve 1s
    timeout retry   1s
    hold other      10s
    hold refused    10s
    hold nx         10s
    hold timeout    10s
    hold valid      10s
    hold obsolete   10s

defaults
    timeout connect 10s
    timeout client 30s
    timeout server 30s
    log global
    mode http
    option httplog

frontend www
    bind *:80
    use_backend stat if { path -i /my-stats }
    use_backend php if { path -i /phpmyadmin }
    default_backend wordpress

backend php
#    reqrep ^([^\ :])\ /phpmyadmin/(.) \1\ /\2
    balance roundrobin
    server php phpmyadmin:80 check resolvers docker init-addr libc,none

backend wordpress
    balance roundrobin
    server wordpress wordp:80 check resolvers docker init-addr libc,none

backend stat
    stats enable
    stats uri /my-stats
    stats refresh 15s
    stats show-legends
    stats show-node
```

Comment: Is this not working for you? What specific questions do you have?

Comment: Hi, 
Thank you for replying, actually no, when I go to http:/VMip/phpmyadmin I recieve 404 not found error.

My question is, what changes should I make to my HAproxy config file to reach phpmyadmin backend server and stick to it.

Comment: Are you sure the 404 is not coming from the php backend? Check the different webservers' logs to see where the request ended up. Try changing the `path -i /phpmyadmin` to `path_beg /phpmydmin`.

Comment: Actually this is weird, I replaced path -i with path_beg still not working...
I believe I should do a redirect there somehow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was found in the documentation  https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html and applied in the following configuration which is working as expected:

```
global
    log          fd@2 local2
    chroot       /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile      /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn      4000
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats expose-fd listeners
    master-worker

resolvers docker
    nameserver dns1 127.0.0.11:53
    resolve_retries 3
    timeout resolve 1s
    timeout retry   1s
    hold other      10s
    hold refused    10s
    hold nx         10s
    hold timeout    10s
    hold valid      10s
    hold obsolete   10s
defaults
    timeout connect 10s
    timeout client 30s
    timeout server 30s
    log global
    mode http
    option httplog

frontend http
    bind *:80
    use_backend stat if { path -i /my-stats }
    option forwardfor
    option http-server-close
    acl phpmyadmin path_dir /phpmyadmin
    use_backend php if phpmyadmin 
    default_backend wordpress




backend php
    mode http
    balance source 
    hash-type consistent
    reqirep  ^(GET|POST|HEAD)\ /phpmyadmin/(.*)     \1\ /\2
    acl hdr_location res.hdr(Location) -m found
    rspirep ^Location:\ (http?://phpmyadmin.local(:[0-9]+)?)?(/.*) Location:\ // if hdr_location
    server-template php- 7 phpmyadmin:80 cookie php check resolvers docker init-addr libc,none


backend wordpress
    balance source
    hash-type consistent
    server-template wordp- 7 wordp:80 cookie wordpress check resolvers docker init-addr libc,none

backend stat
    stats enable
    stats uri /my-stats
    stats refresh 15s
    stats show-legends
    stats show-node
```